# Using computed column more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to use a computed column more than once, for example:

```
SELECT col1 / 1.1 as col2, col2 - col3 as col4 FROM table1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "computed column" has a specific meaning for [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx), and this isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `Common Table Expression`

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
     SELECT col1 / 1.1 as col2, 
            col3
     FROM table1
)

SELECT col2, 
       col2 - col3 as col4 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

Not like that. You can use it on a derived table:

```
SELECT col2, col2-col3 col4
FROM (SELECT col1/1.1 col2, col3 FROM table1) A
```

You can also use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT col2,
       col2-col3 col4
FROM table1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT col1/1.1) A(col2)
```